# Входные данные не являются действительной строкой Base-64

Tags: c#, base64

Привет всем! 
Снова у меня проблема с base64.
Функция Convert.FromBase64String отказывается конвертировать строку:

```
"PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBYSFRNTCAxLjAgU3RyaWN0Ly9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly"
```

Опять же онлайн конвертор  https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/ это делает без проблем. Пробовал в конце добавлять '='. Не помогает.

Студия постоянно бьет ошибку:

```
Входные данные не являются действительной строкой Base-64, поскольку содержат символ в кодировке, отличной от Base 64, больше двух символов заполнения или недопустимый символ среди символов заполнения.
```

Comment: Добавьте "==" в конец...

Comment: И дался вам этот сайт для проверки. в гугле вбиваете base64 decode с десяток нормальных сайтов находятся, которые адекватно декодируют, в отличии от того чем вы пользуетесь. Вот например http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/#.Wi1TRFVl_Mo при декодировании вашей строки явно видно, что в конце какой то не допустимый символ, значит у вас строка не целая, в конце лишние биты. боле менее уравновесить позволяют конкретно эту строку `==`. Но лучший способ декодировать на сайте, посмотреть строку, убрать кривые символы и тут же нажать кодировать ее обратно и посмотреть чем отличается код